# Why do most Muslims believe in Adam's Apple while it is never mentioned to be an Apple?

Tags: islamic-basis, adam-and-eve

It is never clearly mentioned that it is an apple in Quran. What was mentioned is a *tree*. So why do most Muslims believe it is an Apple? Is it a fairy tale or it has a supporting proof?

Comment: Why do you think Muslims belives it is an Apple? When I think about it "forbidden fruit" comes to mind, not an Apple. Maybe christian belief affects some people?

Comment: Or maybe Jewish beliefs affected some who belief its _forbidden fruit_

Comment: If someone is believing something that is against Quran, how do you call him a Muslim?

Comment: Who said all the questions are from Muslims?? and non muslims do not believe in quran!!!

Comment: Jews do not have the apple in their Torah either it is strictly Christian

Comment: Yes, But Jews strictly have the _Forbidden Fruit_

Comment: According to certain traditions, Adam ate wheat to be expelled and not an apple. (See: Islam in Practice: Religious Beliefs in a Persian Village)

Comment: @Hajusef. Nope. It's nowhere in the Christian Bible either. It's identified only as a fruit. The idea it was an apple is actually partly an artifact of the English language changing over time (the English word *apple* was once a generic word for any fruit).

Answer (score 6):

It was not an apple, and was not a known earthly fruit because it did not take place on Earth. When Adam and his wife (that is not called Eve in Quran) tasted the tree then they were sent to Earth.

> فَدَلَّاهُمَا بِغُرُورٍ ۚ فَلَمَّا ذَاقَا الشَّجَرَةَ بَدَتْ لَهُمَا
>   سَوْآتُهُمَا وَطَفِقَا يَخْصِفَانِ عَلَيْهِمَا مِن وَرَقِ الْجَنَّةِ ۖ
>   وَنَادَاهُمَا رَبُّهُمَا أَلَمْ أَنْهَكُمَا عَن تِلْكُمَا الشَّجَرَةِ
>   وَأَقُل لَّكُمَا إِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ لَكُمَا عَدُوٌّ مُّبِينٌ
>
> So he led them on by delusion; and when they tasted the tree, their
>   shameful parts revealed to them, so they took to stitching upon
>   themselves leaves of the Garden. And their Lord called to them, 'Did
>   not I prohibit you from this tree, and say to you, "Verily Satan is
>   for you a manifest foe"?'

As Quran says 'they tasted the tree' NOT the apple. Quran as the ultimate source of Islam has said the final word and a Muslim is not allowed to invent any saying on behalf on Allah.